# How to dynamically create and name data frames in a for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to generate data frame subsets for each respondent in a data frame using a for loop.
I have a large data frame with columns titled "StandardCorrect", "NameProper", "StartTime", "EndTime", "AScore", and "StandardScore" and several thousand rows.
I want to make a subset data frame for each person's name so I can generate statistics for each respondent.
I tried using a for loop

> `for(name in 1:length(NamesList)){ name <- DigiNONA[DigiNONA$NameProper == NamesList[name], ] }`

NamesList is just a list containing all the levels of NamesProper (which isa factor variable)

All I want the loop to do is each iteration, generate a new data frame with the name "NamesList[name]" and I want that data frame to contain a subset of the main data frame where NameProper corresponds to the name in the list for that iteration.

This seems like it should be simple I just can;t figure out how to get r to dynamically generate data frames with different names for each iteration.

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: The assign() function is what you're looking for, I believe. Check out the first option here...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71885894/how-do-you-group-data-with-the-same-name-in-a-vector/71886420#71886420

Comment: Are you sure `NamesList` is an R list? I would have guessed that it was an atomic character vector formed by some code like: NamesList <- unique(DigiNONA$NameProper)`. If my guess is correct it would be better for you understanding of R terminology to call it `NamesVec`, since the extraction functions are a bit different for atomic vectors and lists.

Answer (score 2):

The advice to use `assign` for this purpose is technically feasible, but incorrect in the sense that it is widely deprecated by experienced users of R. Instead what should be done is to create a single list with named elements each of which contains the data from a single individual. That way you don't need to keep a separate data object with the names of the resulting objects for later access.

```
named_Dlist <- setNames( split( DigiNONA, DigiNONA$NameProper),
                         NamesList)
```

This would allow you to access individual dataframes within the `named_Dlist` object:

```
named_Dlist[[ NamesList[1] ]] # The dataframe with the first person in that NamesList vector.
```

It's probably better to use the term list only for true R lists and not for atomic character vectors.